# apply height resize function on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a simple function to adapt the height of a sidebar to the height of the container div.

```
function resizeDiv() {
    vph = $('#target').height()+40;
    minVph = $(window).height()-90; /* non tolgo altezza menu per compensare il  padding*/
    $('.sidebar').css({'min-height': minVph + 'px'});   
    $('.sidebar').css({'height': vph + 'px'});  
    
}
```

It works fine but I want it to cover also the event when I load dinamically something into the container. On load of that content I want to recalculate the height of the sidebar.

```
$('.link').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('ul.nav li').removeClass('active');
    dest=$(this).attr('href');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
    $('#target').fadeTo(200,0.1,function(){
      $(this).load(dest).fadeTo(900,1,function(){
        resizeDiv();  
      });
    });
});
```

This will not trigger the height adjustment after the `#target` has finished loading. What am I doing wrong? I thought that placing it as callback of the fadeTo would have triggered it after the content in `#target` has rendered but seems not. How to make it triggered after the content has fully load so that the browser knows the final height of `#target`?

Comment: As per the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/load/) if you want to run code *after* loading server content has finished, put the code in a callback and pass that as 2nd argument to `.load`. You're chaining, which runs immediately.

Comment: that's not going to solve the issue at all. Also if I put it as callback of the load I won't get the expected result

Comment: @ChrisG actually it turns out that the page loaded has some dinamic space (a canvas where a graph is rendered) even if the canvas size is pre-defined) and this lead to the issue. Adding the `resizeDiv()` as callback of the graph fixed the issue.

Comment: Ah, yes, the loaded content changing its height would cause issues

Comment: @ChrisG it shouldn't since the canvas size is defined in the html and shouldn't change but seems that the js is re-rendering it.

Comment: You could wrap the canvas in a fixed-height container